# onLongClick show menu options

Tags: android, contextmenu, menuitem, onlongclicklistener

Its my first time here, I'm looking the answer for this question for 2 days and nothing works.
Here is, I want to show the MenuOptions (edit,delete) when users hold the selected item, long press.
My code:

```
public class ProjetoProTelefoneActivity extends ListActivity {
public final static String ID_EXTRA = "br.com.DaniloDeLuca.ProjetoProTelefone._ID";
Cursor modelo = null;
RestaurantAdapter adapter = null;
RestauranteHelper helper=null;
SharedPreferences prefs=null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    helper = new RestauranteHelper(this);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    initList();
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    helper.close();
}
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view,
        int position,long id){
    Intent i=new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DetailForm.class);
    i.putExtra(ID_EXTRA, String.valueOf(id));
    startActivity(i);
}

public void onListItemLongClic( View view,int position,Menu menu){
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.option,menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

//hook into menu button for activity 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.option,menu);
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
/// when menu button option selected 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.add){
        startActivity(new Intent(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, DetailForm.class));
        return(true);
    }
    else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.prefs){

        startActivity(new Intent(this, EditPreferences.class));
        return(true);
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefListener=
        new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
                    String key) {
                if(key.equals("sort_order")){
                    initList();
                }

            }
};
private void initList(){
    if(modelo!=null){
        stopManagingCursor(modelo);
        modelo.close();
    }
    modelo =helper.getAll(prefs.getString("sort_order","nome DESC"));
    startManagingCursor(modelo);

    adapter = new RestaurantAdapter(modelo);       
    setListAdapter(adapter); 

}

class RestaurantAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    RestaurantAdapter(Cursor c) {
      super(ProjetoProTelefoneActivity.this, c);
    }

    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt,
                         Cursor c) {
      RestaurantHolder holder=(RestaurantHolder)row.getTag();

      holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
    }


    public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c,
                         ViewGroup parent) {
      LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
      View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
      RestaurantHolder holder=new RestaurantHolder(row);

      row.setTag(holder);

      return(row);
    }
  }

  static class RestaurantHolder {
    private TextView name=null;
    private TextView address=null;
    private ImageView icon=null;

    RestaurantHolder(View row) {
      name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
      address=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
      icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor r,RestauranteHelper helper) {
      name.setText(helper.getNome(r));
      address.setText(helper.getEnd(r));


      if (helper.getTipo(r).equals("casa")) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.casa_icon);
      }
      else if (helper.getTipo(r).equals("apartamento")) {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.apartamento_icon);
      }
      else {
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.comercio_ico);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Thats work only when I choose the MenuButton. but I want to make the "MenuButton" activity to be the LongPress action, I dont know if its clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to `registerForContextMenu`, that is register your `ListView` against the `Activity` so that on a long press on it a new menu will be created and shown to the user. See

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29

Comment: @Danilo Pereira De Luca: You wont get it to work in any other way, you need a `ContextMenu` object and you cannot instantiate one of those yourself. Only the `Activity` (its internals) can instantiate `Menu`, `SubMenu`, `ContextMenu` and the like... and for a `ContextMenu`, the `Activity` will instantiate one and give it to you only if you `registerForContextMenu`.

Comment: but know i dont know to make this option menu work, it appears, but dont process anything...

Comment: @Danilo Pereira De Luca: Look for `onContextItemSelected`